# Generalized eigenvalue problem using ARPACK

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigenvalues

Is it possible to solve the eigenvalue problem:

$$Ax = \lambda Mx$$

using ARPACK when $A$ and $M$ are both non-symmetric complex matrices? According to [this](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/node138.html) documentation, the function `znaupd` only works when $M$ is symmetric positive definite. I have verified that the results are only correct when $M$ meets this requirement. I have heard that Matlab's `eigs` function is loosely based on ARPACK and it is able to handle non-symmetric $M$ matrices. Do they just convert it to a standard eigenvalue problem?

If this is not possible using ARPACK, what are some alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the documentation closer, it recommends converting the problem to a standard eigenvalue problem when $A$ and $M$ are non-Hermitian positive semi-definite. Section 3.2.2 from the ARPACK documentation:

[image]